# Search multiple search terms

Tags: php, mysql

How to search multiple fields using the following code:

```php
if (count($error) < 1) {

   $searchSQL = "SELECT sid, sdate, stitle, slocation, skategori, stype, sbody, slist FROM job_search WHERE ";

   # grab the search types.
   $types = array();
   $types[] = isset($_GET['title'])?"`stitle` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
   $types[] = isset($_GET['desc'])?"`skategori` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
   $types[] = isset($_GET['list'])?"`slist` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';          
        $types = array_filter($types, "removeEmpty"); 

   if (count($types) < 1) {

      $types[] = "`sbody` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'"; 
      $andOr = isset($_GET['matchall'])?'AND':'OR';
      $searchSQL .= implode(" {$andOr} ", $types) . " ORDER BY `stitle`"; 
      $searchResult = mysql_query($searchSQL) or trigger_error("Error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$searchSQL}");

   }
}
```

I am using a checkbox in the `$types = array();` and if no checkbox is selected the search will use `$types[] = "sbody LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'";`.

What I am wondering is how can I make multiple `$types[]` in the `{$searchTermDB}`and just search all the fields using  `LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'";`?

Comment: have you looked into MATCH AGAINST?

Comment: Just so you have a reference for what @KaiQing is talking about: [Match Against](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html). That is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: A Boolean Full Text Search will work too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: @KaiQing How would I go about integrating a fulltext boolean into my current scripting? Apologies for the hassle, I am still a beginner in PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT sid, sdate, stitle, slocation, skategori, stype, sbody, slist 
FROM job_search 
WHERE MATCH(`stitle`, `skategori`, `slist`) 
AGAINST('{$searchTermDB}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

You can build the field string similar to how you currently do it. the above is a basic example of what a full query may look like.

Just to note, you really should be using something like PDO or mysqli to handle database communication. mysql_ functions are deprecated.

Comment: Thankyou, I am still working out PDO and not far off getting the hang of it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution. Full credit to @Kaiqing for the help. I dropped the  $types = array(); and replaced it with the following:

```
  // If there are no errors, lets get the search going.
   if (count($error) < 1) {
      $searchSQL = "
      SELECT sid, sdate, stitle, slocation, skategori, stype, sbody, slist 
      FROM job_search 
      WHERE MATCH(`stitle`, `skategori`, `slist`, `sbody`, `slocation`) 
      AGAINST('{$searchTermDB}' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ";

      $searchResult = mysql_query($searchSQL) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was:        {$searchSQL}");
```

I am not using PDO and the safe option is to use PDO methods.